# Grid Template Column issue on Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'd like to have the same efect as in the auto-fill effect in the following link:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/JrLdBQ

I tried the following, but it is not working

```
grid grid-cols-[auto-fill_minmax(100px,_1fr)]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the **repeat** part, like this: `grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,_minmax(100px,_1fr))]`

Here is a working example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/HzSYGTAji7

Comment: thanks you so much , i was using the suggestion by the documenation
"grid grid-flow-col auto-cols-fr", however i cannot  try to control  starting a new col is its over size, by the way can we using grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,_minmax(100px,_1fr))] with setting the max column size = 6 , if the column is over 6 , then starting a NEW ROW